# how to determine a Geolocation is within radius distance from another Geolocation?

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field, geolocation

I have two location fields of type Geolocation named point1 and point2. I have one radius field of type Number(6,2). i need to determine whether point2 is located within radius distance from point1 or not. How can this be determined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [DISTANCE](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#DISTANCE) function available so this formula should work:

```
DISTANCE(Point1__c, Point2__c, 'km') <= RadiusInKm__c
```

(or use 'mi' for miles).

Comment: How can this be achieved in apex without using SOQL ?

Comment: @Walker This is a formula function so can be used in several places not just SOQL. If you need to do this in Apex I think you will need to write the maths code yourself - examples and links here [Calculate distance between two places on accounts from a VF page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/557/calculate-distance-between-two-places-on-accounts-from-a-vf-page).